# How to add "swagger": "2.0" in my generated swagger json in laravel using "darkaonline/l5-swagger" package

Tags: php, laravel, swagger

I want to add "swagger": "2.0" in my generated json file for swagger

**my current json is**

```
{
    "openapi": "3.0.0",
    "info": {
        "title": "Ubi Api",
        "description": "Ubi Api Documenation",
        "contact": {
            "email": "admin@abc.com"
        },
        "license": {
            "name": "Apache 2.0",
            "url": "http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html"
        },
        "version": "0.0.1"
    }.....
```

**Expected Json i want**

```
{
    "openapi": "3.0.0",
    "swagger": "2.0",
    "info": {
        "title": "Ubi Api",
        "description": "Ubi Api Documenation",
        "contact": {
            "email": "admin@abc.com"
        },
        "license": {
            "name": "Apache 2.0",
            "url": "http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html"
        },
        "version": "0.0.1"
    }.....
```

can someone help me to solve this issue

Comment: Hi, Can you plz show us what have you tried that we could look?

Comment: Does this help? https://github.com/DarkaOnLine/L5-Swagger#i-am-still-using-swagger-swg-annotation

Comment: Did you Set environment variable SWAGGER_VERSION  in your .env file ?

Comment: ya i tried but it not changed anything